# Login using secure social2 Yahoo

Tags: oauth, yahoo-api, securesocial

SecureSocial module for play 1.x supports login using Yahoo, but in SecureSocial2 Yahoo is not in list of providers. Yahoo supoorts  OAuth1 I tried to customise the code but it didn't worked. Is there any alternative???

Answer (score 0):

Adding the Yahoo provider should not be difficult. You can create a new one by extending OAuth2Provider.  It basically involves implementing the fillProfile method that gets the user information (eg: name, email, etc) from Yahoo.  The authentication part is handled by the OAuth2Provider class.

You can use the FacebookProvider as a guide and change the API calls according to what Yahoo provides.